# What is the 'data' in window.history.replaceState

Tags: javascript, html

We are working on a project using window.history.replacestate. Unfortunately we aren't very good at javascript.

Essentially we are using it to replace any number of shortlinks to the 'root' link. For example :

```
domain.com/fJfk8
domain.com/9dkDl
domain.com/fjgdD
```

would all 'appear' as :

```
domain.com/nice_url
```

It doesn't have to work so we'll put the javascript in the page and in the browsers it does then great and if it doesn't, they get the shortcode.

Note : we *don't* want history !

So we are just using :

```
window.history.replaceState('Object','Nice URL Title', '/nice_url');
```

The question is that this appears to work but we don't understand the 'Object' (data) part.

What exactly is it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `Object` parameter to arbritary data, which will be available in the `state` parameter of the `event` object which is available in the `popstate` event.

In other words, you can set it to whatever you want, to help you restore the webpage to the desired state when the user navigates through their history.

For more information, see the [MDC documentation on window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method).

```
window.history.replaceState({
    foo: 'bar'
}, 'Nice URL Title', '/nice_url');

window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    if (typeof e.state == "object" && e.state.foo == "bar") {
        alert("Blah blah blah");
    }
};

window.history.go(-1);
```

Comment: OK (Quickly reads what the heck popstate is..). So.. in our instance, as we don't need to do anything if user returns via history because Url will work in changed state - we could just leave this empty ?

Comment: @Mike: You most likely will. If a users navigates backwards in their history to a page that is on the history stack through `pushState` or `replaceState`, the page will not update automatically; it's up to you to capture the `onpopstate` event and change the page to the desired state.